# Is there any file in NUnit like we have in testNG.xml

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

Thanks in Advace.

I am relatively new to NUnit + selenium frameworks having completely worked in testng till now.

Having browsed lot of documentations without any success, I want to know if there is any TestNG.xml like file in NUnit where we can specify different suite and tests to run?

Also would like to know SuiteBuilders and TestBuilder in NUnit and any code example would be of great help

Answer (score 0):

By default there isn't a file that you can use to define your tests - but you can use your own `TestCaseSource` in NUnit that you can use to read parameters from an XML file.

There are a bunch of examples available of how to use it on the NUnit repo:

https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseSource-Attribute

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually my question is about is there any testNG.xml like file in NUnit and does  SuiteBuilders and TestBuilder serve the same purpose?